# Hide and Un-hide rows based off a cell value (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to get this code to cooperate as intended. I Think it's a simple logic error.

```
If Worksheets("input").Range("B31").Value = "?TEXT" Then
    Worksheets("Customer Report").Rows("22").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("Customer Report").Rows("23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Worksheets("Customer Report").Rows("23").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("Customer Report").Rows("22").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

The goal is that if cell B31 in Sheet 1 contains "Blah blah TEXT" then to hide row 22 and show row 23. If it just contains "Blah blah" then to show row 22 and hide row 23.

Comment: Will "TEXT" always be at the end?

Comment: Yes, I was uncertain if wildcard was indicated by * or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Like` with `*` as the wildcard.

> `Worksheets("input").Range("B31").Value Like "*TEXT"`

Also there is no need for the If.  We can simply do the test.

> `Rows().Hidden = 1 = 1`

The `1=1` will resolve to true and the row will be hidden.

Also `Rows().EntireRow` is redundant.

```
Worksheets("Customer Report").Rows("22").Hidden = Worksheets("input").Range("B31").Value Like "*TEXT"
Worksheets("Customer Report").Rows("23").Hidden = Not Worksheets("input").Range("B31").Value Like "*TEXT"
```

---

We can lessen the amount of duplicate typing further:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("input").Range("B31")
With Worksheets("Customer Report")
    .Rows("22").Hidden = rng.Value Like "*TEXT"
    .Rows("23").Hidden = Not rng.Value Like "*TEXT"
End With
```